# How to handle currency redenomination in gnucash?

Tags: gnucash

Government of my country is planning to [redenominate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redenomination) my local currency.
For example, we have conversion rate 15000:1 local to USD. After redomination happen it will be 1.5:1 local to USD.

I don't know how to handle this in gnucash in a way it won't affect income/expenses reports.

Thanks for any advice

Comment: I think it depends on whether gnucash will support both the old and new currency or not. If so, it seems straightforward. If it won't support both, reading [this](http://www.gnucash.org/docs/v2.4/C/gnucash-guide/chapter_currency.html), and in particular [this](http://www.gnucash.org/docs/v2.4/C/gnucash-guide/currency_acct1.html#currency_acct_user2), it looks like it's doable but only with some gnarly workarounds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out that government is going to change ISO 4217 code of local currency. 
So Gnucash adaptation to this would be easy and mostly mechanical.

1. Duplicate all accounts you have with new ISO currency
2. Set fixed rate between old and new currency
3. Transfer all asserts from old accounts
4. Delete old accounts